# Set field of Objects in List to identical value and return a list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a function that returns a list of Objects. After getting that list, I want to set a field in each of these objects to an identical value. Is there a way with which I could reduce the three (mock) lines of code below to one?

```
List<someObjects> aList = functionReturningList();
aList.stream().forEach(m -> m.setField(fieldValue));
anotherList.addAll(aList);
```

Comment: `anotherList.addAll(functionReturningList().stream().forEach(m -> m.setField(fieldValue)).collect(Collectors.toList()));` ***:)***

Comment: Set field in map operation and return itself

Comment: @anacron aren't those two terminal operations one after another? You can't even chain those.

Comment: Exactly, @Eugene. `forEach()` returns `void`. One might use `peek()`, but it’s not meant for this use.

Comment: @Eugene, Oops! Yeah, I was thinking the `forEach` was `map`. Sorry about that. It would be: `anotherList.addAll(functionReturningList().stream().map(m -> {m.setField(fieldValue);return m;}).collect(Collectors.toList()));` which is same as your answer ***:)***

Comment: padrino, I prefer your code as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't really understand why you want to do that in a single line, but here is one way:

```
 anotherList.addAll(functionReturningList()
                      .stream()
                      .map(m -> { m.setField(fieldValue); return m;})
                      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Once this is written, it certainly a lot more than a "single line". Besides the `map` is performing a side-effect operation and the collector is copying the entire collection too. Your initial approach is thus a *better* one.

And `List` has `forEach` too, you don't have to stream to get that method.

Comment: first, up-vote. maybe using `Stream#peek` is more simpler .

Comment: That stretches the term “line”. Besides abusing the API by performing a side effect within the mapping function, it is less efficient than the OP’s original code by performing an obsolete copying step of the entire list instead of just adding them directly to the target list.

Answer (score 6):

The only thing, I would change in you code, is to omit the `stream()` call when you just want to do `forEach`:

```
List<someObjects> aList = functionReturningList();
aList.forEach(m -> m.setField(fieldValue));
anotherList.addAll(aList);
```

If you really insist on doing it in one operation, you may use

```
functionReturningList().forEach(m -> {
    m.setField(fieldValue));
    anotherList.add(m);
});
```

however, there is no advantage in doing it that way. If there will be any recognizable performance difference at all, the former is likely more efficient than the latter, as it allows the JVM to optimize the `addAll` operation to a single memory transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Use *map* instead a *foreach*, then *collect* to list and *addAll* the result to the another list

see this example:

```
List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
List<Integer> myList2 = new ArrayList<>();
myList2.addAll(myList.stream().map(x -> x = 0).collect(Collectors.toList()));

System.out.println(myList);
System.out.println(myList2);
```